# Number of ways that 'n' people can be seated on 'n' seats such that each person can only occupy specific seats (details of seats provided)

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Suppose, there are 5 people, numbered 1,2,3,4 and 5, and there are 5 seats, named A,B,C,D and E. Also,the list of seats which can be occupied by each person is given. For example, it is given that person 1 can occupy seats A,B,C person 2 can occupy seats D,E etc.

Also, for my specific problem, seat A can be occupied by all five people.

Comment: How many seat choices for the first person? Given that choice,   how many seat choices for the second person? Etc.

Comment: Unless there is some very particular pattern to the list of seats which can be occupied by each person, this sounds like a job for brute force. Just go through every possible (and impossible) combination one by one. (There are 120 of them in total, and loads of them can be excluded quickly. Shouldn't take more than a couple of minutes.)